# Looping with "Table" over two variables

Tags: list-manipulation

so essentially, I have a table:

```
table= Table[0, {5}, {30}, {6}];
```

I have now been trying to loop the functions below over level 2, (30) of the table and then looping it over dimension 3, (6).

I have gotten the loop over dimension 2  to work:

```
a=Flatten[Position[Transpose[table], 
   Min[Table[Max[Transpose[table][[p]]], {p, 1, 30}]]]][[1]]
```

This gives me the minimax of dimension 2 of the data. What I am failing at is looping this over dimension 3 also, ultimately producing a list of six different values in a.

Closest in my mind would be something like:

```
a=Table[Flatten[
   Position[Transpose[teststat], 
    Min[Table[Max[Transpose[teststat][[n]][[i]]], {n, 1, 30}]]]], {i, 
   1, 6}];
```

but this is clearly  wrong.

The first line of input data would be: {2.95095, 0.186768, 0.10373, 0.0430614, 0.13822, 0.0535124}, total data is this x30 x5.

Expected output would be something like: {2,3,7,22,11,44}
I suppose my question can be reduced to: where do I have to place the second variable definition [[i]] and {i,1,6}

Context is: the table contains test statistics of 6 different model variations for the top 30 percentiles of data with 5 implicates. Within the percentiles I want to find the position of the value which minimizes the maximum of the test-statistics, for everyone of the six model variations.

Thank you for any and all suggestions. 
B

Comment: The first line of input data would be: {2.95095, 0.186768, 0.10373, 0.0430614, 0.13822, 
  0.0535124}, total data is this x30 x5.

Comment: Expected output something like: {2,3,7,22,11,44}

Comment: Is the input example sufficient? I tried to copy and paste one of the first five dimensions, but the word limit.

Comment: The point is, I think it is not clear what exactly you want to do so a description of your procedure would be on topic. It is clearly more than just looping. Also, the emphasis was on **minimal**. p.s. `Function[arr, Position[arr, Min[Max /@ Transpose@arr]]] /@ table`?

Comment: I suppose my question can be reduced to: where do I have to place the second variable definition [[i]] and {i,1,6}.

Comment: I still don't understand your question after 3 reads or so. Am I correct to assume that you have a 3D Array/Matrix/Whatever and you just want to find the $minimax$ value of each of the "slices" in your data? In your input example it would be the 6 $minimax$ for arrays of dimensions 5x30

Comment: Thank you for trying to understand! I am not doing a good job explaining. Yes, it is a 5x30x6 matrix. As explanation: this is about data with 5 implicates of 30 data points (representing percentiles), and 6 model variations of both. For each model specification I would like to find the position of the value in the "percentiles", where the maximum of the values are minimized. The First code above works, but only for one model variation. I would simply like to include all model variations of the 3rd dimension. I hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: In that case you just have to iterate over the last parameter, and second one. I'll put an answer, but am still unsure if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can create a function such as this:

```
minimax[table_] := 
 Module[{slices, val, pos = {}}, 
  slices = table[[All, All, #]] & /@ Range[Last@Dimensions@table];
  val = Min@Max@slices[[#]] & /@ Range[Last@Dimensions@table];
  pos = Position[slices[[#]], val[[#]]] & /@ 
    Range[Last@Dimensions@table]
  ]
```

Then just run the

`minimax[t]` where `t` where `t` is your table.

EDIT: This way you will get the positions in the second level of your table.

EDIT2: cleared up the code this will give you pairs of indices, of the first two levels

Comment: Thats great, thank you very much! I was thinking of a way easier solution all this time tho, like you mentioned in the comment above: to just iterate over the second parameter. Thats at least what i was trying to get to work but I just couldnt figure out placement etc.

Comment: Actually looking at my code .... I did a horrible job. You can do the same simply by `Min@Max@table[All,All,#]&/@Range[Last@Dimensions@table]`

Comment: Hmm, I just ran it, and it works great. However, it gives me the values, rather than the positions somewhere out of 1-30. Thats why I was using position before. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Yes, I see This gets the values, I will edit the answer to give the positions too.

Comment: See the update, or alternatively the oneliner in this comment section can be modified too to be basically
`Position[Min@Max@table[All,All,#],table[All,All,#]]&/@Range[Last@Dimensions@table]`

Comment: Strangely, using the function defined above with the pos= line of code under the edit produces an empty matrix. I am checking whether I made a mistake in applying the code.

Comment: Also when applying the standalone Position command, mathematica says the range specification does not have appropriate bounds. Strange.

Comment: this means I am very unattentive :D I just assumed I won't have syntax errors, the latest edit should help, I tested

Comment: Ah, it produces the results nicely. My final question: :) what would I need to change in the code if I only wanted to get the position in dimension 2? Thank you very much man!

Comment: Lazy answer : just take the second parameters from the answer. Another Lazy answer look at documentation of Position, there's a variable `levelspec` you can sort of ask for the level where you want to search, I just didn't wanna try it out.